# Java scoping issue

Tags: java, regex

Can someone take a look at my code and try to help me figure this out?  this is a regex app that parses user commandline queries.

```
public class InterpretCommand {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        String a;

        Command c = new Command();

        java.util.Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter command: ");
        a = reader.nextLine();

        //String to be scanned is the user input
        String line = a;
        //identifies the order command
        String pattern1 = "(?<=(-)([o]\\s)).*";
        //identifies the filter command
        String pattern2 = "(?<=(-)([f]\\s)).*";

        //create pattern objects
        Pattern r1 = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
        Pattern r2 = Pattern.compile(pattern2);

        //create matcher object
        Matcher m1 = r1.matcher(a);
        Matcher m2 = r2.matcher(a);

        //for Order match
        if (m1.find()){
            String s1 = m1.group(0);
            System.out.println(s1);  ** this works **
            System.out.println(c.returnActions1(s1)); **says print not applicable for arguments**

        }
        else if (m2.find()){
            String s2 = m2.group(0);
            System.out.println(s2); **this works**
            System.out.println(c.returnActions2(s2));  **says print not applicable for arguments**
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No match for given input");
        }

    }

    public class Command {

            String a;

            public void returnActions1(String s1){

                String[] commands = s1.split(",");

                for(int i=0; i<commands.length; i++){

                    if(commands[i].equals("TITLE")){
                        //SELECT "TITLE" from <dataframe>
                }
                    else if(commands[i].equals("DATE")){
                        //SELECT "DATE" from <dataframe>
                    }
            }
        }

            public void returnActions2(String s2){

                String[] commands = s2.split(",");

                for(int i=0; i<commands.length; i++){

                    if(commands[i].equals("TITLE")){
                        //ORDER <dataframe> by "TITLE"
                }
                    else if(commands[i].equals("DATE")){
                        //ORDER <dataframe> by "DATE"
                    }
                }
            }
    }


}
```

Any thoughts on what Im messing up?  Im sure that Im failing to scope my variables correctly, or maybe just instantiate them in general.  the problem arises when I pass my main variables to other class methods within main.

Comment: what problem arises? Describe the problem a bit more.

Comment: Is it intentional that Command is an inner class?

Comment: Command is not an inner class--its just how it copied from Eclipse.

Comment: The problem is that for some reason I cant use s1 as a parameter for my Command class method.  i dont know why?  i think it has something to do with instantiation ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you actually want Command to be an inner class:

```
Command c = new Command();
```

fails to compile with error

```
error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

making Command `static` will take care of this problem.

Then,

```
System.out.println(c.returnActions1(s1));
```

fails to compile with error

```
error: 'void' type not allowed here
```

which is a logical consequence of the definition of returnActions as

```
public void returnActions1(String s1) {
```

As I have no idea what you actually want to do in that method, I can only suggest to change its return type

```
public String returnActions1(String s1) {
```

and add a return statement returning whatever that method is supposed to return.

Comment: Command is not an inner class--that is just how I copy and pasted it from Eclipse (new class, new tab).  sorry

Comment: I can assure you it is an inner class - but that just means that you won't have the first issue.  The second issues remains the same.

Comment: "The method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void) "

Comment: btw the Command class methods are not fully built--i included comments below the if statements to imply what they *will* return

Comment: see my answer: you declared that method "public ***void*** returnActions", ie, not returning anything.

Comment: so once I complete my Command class methods (with return statements) I will be able to call those static methods in main?

Comment: you will, if you *correct* their return types.  And if Command isn't an inner class (but in the code you show it **is** an inner class) but a regular class living in its own file, its methods don't have to be static.  Nobody mentioned static methods btw...